# Two tables with composite key are joined in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have four tables in SQL Server, the image the tables and relations.

[image]

The problem is when I use Entity Framework the `GroupAdmins` and `GroupMembers` tables is joined into one table, the image show the situation:

[image]

I want to get the four tables in Entity Framework. What should I do ?

**Update**

The real problem is that I can't add or delete items for `GroupAdmins` and `GroupMembers` tables in the same way as I do with other tables. For example, if I want to add item to `AspNetUsers`, I use this :

```
using (var db=new DatabaseContext())
      {
        AspNetUsers user = new AspNetUsers{Id=1,Email="something@email.com"};
        db.AspNetUsers.add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
      }
```

While I can't do the same for `GroupAdmins` and `GroupMembers`, because `GroupAdmins` and `GroupMembers` are not exist.

Comment: That is the way EF handles many-to-many relationships - you won't see the "link" tables that connect two tables in such a relationship.

Comment: @marc_s do you mean that can't separate the tables ?

Comment: No - those are merely link tables to establish a many-to-many relationship - EF will **not** show those, but handle them "behind the scenes" for you. You're not losing any features by this! Just let EF do its work

Comment: @marc_s The real problem is that I can't add or delete items in `GroupAdmins` and `GroupMembers` tables in the same way as I do with other tables. Can you give me a simple example of adding or deleting in such situation.

Comment: You just need to use the collection-based **navigation properties** on the entities that get created from the database!

Comment: only way to get it work is like this: 
                    AspNetUsers x = db.AspNetUsers.Find(UserID);
                    Groups group = new Groups { Name = "test", Type = 0, Date = DateTime.Now, Description = "dis" };
                    group.AspNetUsers.Add(x);
                    db.Groups.Add(group);
                    db.SaveChanges();

This method need additional select statement

Comment: That **IS THE WAY** to do it in EF !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **many-to-many** relationship between two tables, in the relational database, you need a "link" table to connect the two base tables.

EF handles this automatically for you - it doesn't explicitly surface that link table - it handles those inserts and deletes internally, behind the scenes. You **don't need to do anything special at all!** Use this default behavior - don't fight it! It works **to your advantage!**

What you do is basically add new entries in one of the tables into the collection-based **navigation property**, and EF will automatically insert the necessary entries into the relevant link table.

So for instance, you could do something like this:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    AspNetUsers user = new AspNetUsers { Id = 1, Email = "something@email.com" };
    db.AspNetUsers.add(user);

    // get a group to add the new user to
    Groups g = db.Groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name = "SomeGroupName");

    if(g != null)
    {
        // since I don't have your EDMX model here, I don't know if "AspNetUsers" for the "Groups"
        // refers to the "GroupMembers" or the "GroupAdmins" connection - *YOU* can see this when
        // you look at the EDMX model designer!
        g.AspNetUsers.Add(user);
    }

    // now when you save, you'll get a new user in "AspNetUsers", AND ALSO: you'll get an entry
    // in either "GropuMembers" or "GroupAdmins" that contains the two ID's - AspNetUsers.Id 
    // and the Id for the group with the name of "SomeGroupName"
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Comment: Just as a side note, it only makes sense to have these many-to-many bridge tables available in the model if they include additional information, for example the date when the relation was created or any other attribute. I.e. if they include additional columns, apart from the related tables keys.

Comment: @JotaBe: correct - and in that case, EF **will** surface those tables. Only if the contain nothing but the two PK from the linked tables will EF "hide" them behind the scenes

Comment: None of this works with database-first. EF won't create *anything* for you; you're responsible for setting up all the database tables as they should be.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: absolutely correct - EF in a database-first approach doesn't create any tables - I never said anything like that. What I mean is **once the tables are in place**, when you create the user and associate with a group as I have shown, EF will create the **rows** in the existing tables for you - that's all